# onClick event on javascript using arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<button onClick={ ()=>this.funtionname("hello")}>ChangeState</button>
```

is this same as arrow function??
Does onClick() is arrow function in this case??

Comment: `this` is different in arrow functions

Comment: `()=>this.funtionname("hello")` is an arrow function. `onClick` is event listener and `()=>this.funtionname("hello")` is event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Arrow function extends `this` property from it's parent environment, and it does not create it's own. In this example, it will return it's parent environment, aka the `parent component`. Regular function will most probably return `undefined`. But in usual html `onclick` function, they both will return the `event target`, aka the `clicked element`.